# Modernizr mq does not behave like matchMedia

Tags: javascript, modernizr, matchmedia

given this code:

```
mql = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 800px)");
mql.addListener(mqlHandler);
function mqlHandler(mql) {
  if(mql.matches) {
    alert('OK');
};
```

and this other code:

```
if(Modernizr.mq("(max-width: 800px)")) {
  alert('OK');
};
```

the `matchMedia` version works as expected, it pops the alert when the size of the screen is less than 800px, no matter how many times i resize the page, however, the second one just pops an alert when i reload the page with a screen width less than 800px, if a resize the screen after that no alerts are shown.

I read this from de Modernizr docs, "A max-width or orientation query will be evaluated against the current state, which may change later."
This refers to this particular behavior or there are something wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2):

Modernizr.mq doesn't reevaluate on resize. It only checks when it is executed. The equivalent code would be

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    if(Modernizr.mq("(max-width: 800px)")) {
      alert('OK');
    };   
}, true);
```

Comment: I see, Modernizr justs makes a check, your example works fine but triggers the event every time the window width changes so i think is better to use de mediaMatch approach, thx!

Comment: Yep! you can check out respond.js if you need older browser support.